# Javascript: Execute a function only, when a specific file on host exists

Tags: javascript

This is the function, i want to execute, when the plugin "xupnpd" is installed on the host (a linux settopbox). The function is placed in a html document with other  class links. To check the plugins existance, i would check the existance of the binary. If the plugin is not installed, the link should not be visible. I found some methods to check a files existance, but i don't know, how to combine this ...

`<script language="JavaScript">
                    //document.write('<a class=linelink2 href="' + window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + ':4044' + window.location.pathname + '" target=main >xupnpd</a> ' );`

Comment: JS is generally used in a browser context which has no way of looking for existence of files, for security reasons.

Comment: This should be done on the server side. Only your server knows whether it has that plugin installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know this plugin at all but the [API](http://xupnpd.org/t/api.html) says you can interact with it using HTTP Get requests, as your link is doing. Instead of checking if the file exists, could you do a request to see if you get a response? This also has the benefit of checking that the plugin is running, not just installed.

For example (using jquery for clearness):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var url = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + ':4044/ui/api';

$.get(url, null, function(){
    $('#linelinkHolder').html('<a class=linelink2 href="' + window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + ':4044' + window.location.pathname + '" target=main >xupnpd</a> ');
});
</script>

<div id="linelinkHolder"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, well, we have no get on the box and no jquery. Is it possible to look for the `"HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK"` answer? Because, we have other plugins too, which will deliver a webinterface, so we could adapt this for other plugins. To clear this up, i am no developer, our project currently only has two main developers, who work on other things and some contributers. I only try to fix and extend the webinterface a little bit with my poor html knowledge ...

Comment: yes you should be able to do the same using a raw [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest), and check for a `200` response status. I just did it in jquery to make the approach clear.